# From MS .NET to Web development options on Mac OS X

Tags: macos

I'm a .NET web developer, who's bought a Mac, and is interested in doing web development natively on the Mac.

I've never developed outside of the Microsoft sandbox, and I'm looking for something new, but still in web development.

I've looked into [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)), but it looks like trying to fit a square peg into a round hole, am I wrong? Like for example, I can't do breakpoints on my web apps?

Here are my criteria:

- say what you will about Microsoft, but I'm simply not interested in command-line setups, or weird configuration stuff, I just want it to work
- I'll need a powerful IDE, as good as Visual Studio 2008. I'm particularly fond of [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense), auto-correction, auto-completion, and how it all hangs togethere, and the debugging features
- I know this isn't "cool", but I love strongly typed languages. I find the dynamic aspect of the next generation .NET languages really cool, but I like how it sits within a static world. I know I know, dynamic is cool, but I like strong typing OK, it brings peace to my mind.
- I can definitely do without all the .NET controls, and page life cycle, I'm happy to do the front-end myself, I just want the back-end part to be as friendly, and high level as ASP.NET.
- Oh, and I love all the reflection, generics, and functional stuff, especially LINQ, in C# and VB.NET.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I appreciate any help. But just to make it clear, I'm not interested in VM solutions. To do .NET I'll just [Boot Camp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Camp_%28software%29) into Windows. I'm looking to develop natively on Mac OS X. If I'm wrong about Mono, that would be the best thing.

Otherwise something new might be fun.

**UPDATE**

I decided to have a look at Scala, and for fun, although it isn't web dev, AIR apps too. I tried Mono, but the IDE is still in Beta, and there's no way to use breakpoints in debugging, which is an unnecessary pain.

I am going to look at [Scala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29), and maybe some Java frameworks too.

Comment: So basically you just bought a Mac, but intent to continue as if you where still using Windows? I have an idea; be open to learning new things. Only change can lead to something better (or worse if not changing with wisdom).

Comment: hey, I like and am used to the .NET world. also, I'm open to something new, just because it's Static and simple to use doesn't mean it's windows. I'm ready...I'm just into dynamics is all. other than that, where do I start?

Comment: sorry, I meant to say, I'm not into dynamic languages

Comment: @Andy .. I am basically with PeyloW on this.  But I have to ask you why you bought a Mac in the first place if you want to continue your Windows coding experience?  OS X sits firmly in the *nix camp and the manner of programming things on it has a different philosophy to the Windows world - and I say this from developing software on both and having one of each system sitting on my desk right now.

Comment: @peterM: haha, yeah good question. I'm into film-making, and a lot of photography, and the 17" Pro was the best for this. Programming is what I do for money, but I'm a geek, and I enjoy it too, I like a challange

Comment: andy, I basically agree with your thoughts on the issue but there is nothing that meets all your criteria on the Mac at the moment. Maybe in a few years as Mono and MonoDevelop mature further.

Comment: Don't listen to the naysayers. There's nothing strange about Mono on OS X. These same people probably wouldn't object to you using Perl, Python, C, C++, Objective-C, SmallTalk, Java, or any of a bajillion other languages and dev platforms. Shell scripts are totally nix, yet I can write far more powerful console apps far more quickly using Mono. Maybe other people can't, and maybe it's easier for them to write scripts, but with so many choices, why is it everything but *Mono* is acceptable? Most of the framework is platform-independent in design, but they'd only know that if they tried it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read some interesting articles about [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) - But I haven't tried it myself yet.
It uses static typing and also has functional features.
There is a [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) bundle for it and also Netbeans seems to [offer good Scala support](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Scala).

Comment: had a look, Scala looks pretty interesting

Answer (score 4):

I would definitely take a look at Mono on OSX. There's tons of tools and you don't have to be a command line guy to use it.

- For an IDE take a look at [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) which can now do
  iPhone development
- MonoDevelop is built on top of [Gtk#](http://mono-project.com/GtkSharp) which is a great GUI toolkit
- Another GUI would be to [WinForms](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.windows.forms.aspx&ei=fWbUSq9DlJfwBqTO9PwM&usg=AFQjCNHAb57DeH9-xLNWQ6kYAnmA-MYxfA&sig2=Vb9Jl1DwDnXndPvutVjnuw), but I've never been a big fan

As for web development you can still use MonoDevelop with any of the normal toolkits:

- [WebForms](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET)
- [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/)
- [Silverlight / Moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight)
- etc

For the server you can use [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/), [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/), etc - pick your poison!

Perhaps I'm biased as I've been using Mono since before the 0.3 days, but I'm and fan and it's definitely not like "fitting a square peg into a round hole". It has it's own libraries and ways of doing things and support for almost all of the .NET stack.

Comment: cool, downloading it now to try it. can you just "run" your web app from the IDE, and then step by step using breakpoints? also, is there LINQ to SQL equivilante? how does that work, in terms of the IDE?

Comment: I don't think MonoDevelop is a viable option on the Mac yet. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559852/hitting-breakpoints-in-monodevelop-2-2-beta-1-on-osx

Answer (score 2):

Given the constraints, I think you would be happiest with Java. It is statically typed, has good IDEs (IntelliJ, Eclipse, NetBeans) and is used a lot for web.

Comment: Agreed! The closest you can get to NATIVELY developing for Mac while sticking to something similar to windows, is Java. Only difference is you will have to deploy your apps with the ever so large Java Virtual Machine, and JavaFX library. I haven't gotten to web development with an actual programming language (I come from a web design background, using HTML, javascript, etc), but I will say there are some frame works for web development in Java you should check out.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use VMWare or parallels.

I run Visual Studio in VMWare (on windows 2008 server) runs well

Comment: sorry, I'm looking for something new, and I want to run it natively

Answer (score 1):

I'd look to run Visual Studio under a VM on OSX if I were you. If you're not doing fancy WPF stuff, then your development/deployment experience will be the same.