# Hitting breakpoints in MonoDevelop 2.2 Beta 1 on OSX

Tags: macos, breakpoints, monodevelop

Just installed MonoDevelop 2.2 Beta 1 on OSX Snow Leopard, and all is good.

I created a new ASP.NET web project, and ran it. So far so good. But then I put a breakpoint in the code behind, and it didn't hit it...any ideas why?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no debugger for Mac. It won't work until they actually have one.
This feature works on Windows and Linux. :)

Answer (score 1):

The mono debugger, MDB, does not run on Mac OS yet, so MD is unable to use it to debug Mono apps. Note that where there are no debugger adaptors available in MD there is no "Debug" command, only "Run".

AFAIK, MDB MacOS support should be in Mono 2.6, though I expect it'll be somewhat experimental. When this is shipping, we'll be able to include the MDB adaptor addin in MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 1):

@mhutch
Not sure what you're saying is totally correct: I've installed MonoDevelop 2.2 on my MacBook Pro under OSX Leopard and i have a bright "Debug" button side by side with "Build all projects of all solutions", anyway it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use Mono Develop on OSX is a frustrating and ultimately hopeless exercise. Apart from the lack of debugger support the IDE is unstable, and simple things like copying and pasting text in an editor window is a lottery as to whether it will crash or not.